# Exporting an Excel file with WebAPI, VueJS, EPPlus

Tags: excel, vue.js, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I need to export an excel file that is comprised of formulas, formatted, etc. It's not just a table of data. I.e., top portion will be descriptions/calculations, and then the lower half will loop through a list of items. **Adding this bc I need more functionality than vue-json-excel or vue-json-export offer (I think)**

I know how to do this with webforms/code-behind, but I've been dabbling with VueJS and MVC and am trying to figure out how to get this done with that. I am using EPPlus.

From VueJS, I'm calling a webapi that hits my "reports" controller. For now, I'm just trying to see if I can actually export an Excel file from code-behind.

Right now, when I attempt to export a dummy file... nothing happens? There aren't any errors, but there is no prompt that says "Download file or Open" (or whatever).

```
public class ReportController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string aliases, string startDate, string endDate, string level)
    {         
        //attempting to just export a dummy excel - not working :(         

        MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Resources.AbsenceReport);
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("fileName") { FileName = "Test.xlsx" };
        return response;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? In my Vue portion, I just have:

```
 AR.getTeamReport(aliasesToSearch, startDate, endDate, level)
    .then(response => {
      //IDK MAN WILL IT WORK :X
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.sentToastError(
        "Unable to pull report. Please refresh and try again."
      );
    });
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as EPPlus? I get that your ultimate goal is to generate an Excel file, but you need to figure out how to download a pre-existing file first. Keep your question focus narrow.

Comment: @mason My thought process was to ensure that my question received exposure with folks that are knowledgeable about this or that have encountered this. Since I'm using EPPlus on the backend, perhaps someone who has used that in conjunction with VueJS would be able to help.

Comment: EPPlus is a .NET library that generates files. From Vue's perspective, it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @mason I felt it was relevant because I'm not just spitting out data from vue's end. If that's all I needed, I wouldn't have a problem. Tagging EPPlus maybe would also assist others with a similar scenario with finding this question. But, okay, thanks for your explanation. Do you know how I might be able to get the controller talking with the vue end? It seems like something gets lost between the two or isn't being passed.

Comment: Have you checked you endpoint using something like Postman or Fiddler?